# Is it proper to set jQuery ajax url using php variable inside script tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, absolute-path

I'm working in a framework where not all the pages are the same relative path from the asset directories, so they often use a WWW variable to get the correct path to css, php, js files etc.

I'm setting up a form that submits via ajax, and for the `url` path to work, it will have to be an absolute path, but based on a variable ideally for maintainability.

Since that WWW variable is already set up in the php, I was thinking about including a php page with `<script>` tags and that way I can use the same variable..

Is that considered really kludgy? or is there another way to do it?  Ideally I want to have all the config just in one file to make it more easily portability, which is why I don't just have a js file with the path. So if there's some way to autogenerate it or something...

Comment: Seems fine to me too. That's the way I work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just render that kind of stuff on page instead of incurring a separate request just to get a variable.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var www_var = '<?php echo $www_var; ?>'</script>
```

Comment: makes sense! what I ended up doing on another recommendation is including a meta tag with the php variable echoed out in it.  Your way is a little more direct.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's some complication in using a base-url relative path like `/path/to/foo/`? I personally don't like to mix programming languages like this.  In other words, I consider it not to be proper to do this.

Comment: yeah... the way the cms is built the homepage loads from the root dir and the others from subfolders.